# Why do my enemies with a Nav Mesh Agent and Rigidbodies push underneath my player with a Character Controller?

Tags: character, rigid-bodies, navmesh

I'm using a character controller to manipulate the player in my game, and I have two enemies that use Nav Mesh Agents. When the player is within the enemies radius, the enemy will chase the player, approach it, and attack it. While these are all working fine, the one thing that isn't are my enemies pushing themselves underneath the player. I did a lot of investigation in the issue but I would like to hear some suggestions as to what the issue might be. I will post a video of what is happening, and the code that allows an enemy to approach a player.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.AI;
using System.Linq; // use Linq for grabbing Transforms

public class EnemyPatrol : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject player;
    Transform playerTransform;
    public float playerDistance;
    public float awareAI = 10f;
    public float damping = 6.0f;
    public Transform[] navPoint;
    public int timeToWait = 1;
    public NavMeshAgent agent;
    private int destPoint = 0;
    private Transform goal;
    private LineRenderer line;
    // animator
    private Animator anim;
    // if enemy was shot, fire look at player func()
    public bool enemyShot = false;

    // grab two random points
    private int currentPoint1;
    private int currentPoint2;

    private EnemyAttackAndWalk enemyAttack;

    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        agent.autoBraking = false;

        // animator
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        enemyAttack = GetComponent<EnemyAttackAndWalk>();

        // player transform
        player = GameObject.Find("Player (Mech)");
        playerTransform = player.GetComponent(typeof(Transform)) as Transform;

        line = gameObject.AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        line.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
        line.startColor = Color.blue;
        line.endColor = Color.blue;
        line.startWidth = 0.1f;
        line.endWidth = 0.1f;
        line.positionCount = 0;
        // grab gameobjs with tag Waypoint
        GameObject[] waypoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Waypoint");
        // use Linq to grab Transform from each Waypoint gameobject
        // put those variables into an array of navPoint
        navPoint = waypoints.Select(go => go.transform).ToArray();
        // randomize the patrol points
        int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, navPoint.Length);
        // set randomized patrol point to the goal var
        goal = navPoint[randomIndex];
        agent.destination = goal.position;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        playerDistance = Vector3.Distance(playerTransform.position, transform.position);

        if (playerDistance <= awareAI || enemyShot == true)
        {
            LookAtPlayer();
            Chase();

            //enemyAttack.playerInRange = true;
        }

        if (agent.remainingDistance < 0.1f) // go to point
        {
            StartCoroutine(IsEating());
        }
        // Check if the enemy is at the first point and needs to switch to the second point
        if (agent.destination == navPoint[currentPoint1].position)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(navPoint[currentPoint2].position);
        }
        // Check if the enemy is at the second point and needs to switch to the first point
        else if (agent.destination == navPoint[currentPoint2].position)
        {
            agent.SetDestination(navPoint[currentPoint1].position);
        }



        DrawPath();
    }

    void LookAtPlayer()
    {
        transform.LookAt(playerTransform);
    }

    IEnumerator IsEating()
    {
        agent.isStopped = true;
        anim.SetBool("isEating", true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.9f);
        anim.SetBool("isEating", false);
        agent.isStopped = false;
        GotoNextPoint();
    }

    

    void GotoNextPoint()
    {
        if (navPoint.Length == 0)
            return;

        int randomIndex1 = Random.Range(0, navPoint.Length);
        int randomIndex2;

        do
        {
            randomIndex2 = Random.Range(0, navPoint.Length);
        } while (randomIndex1 == randomIndex2);

        agent.SetDestination(navPoint[randomIndex1].position);

        currentPoint1 = randomIndex1;
        currentPoint2 = randomIndex2;
    }


    void Chase()
    {
        agent.SetDestination(playerTransform.position);

        
    }

    void DrawPath()
    {
        if (agent.path.corners.Length < 2)
        {
            line.positionCount = 0;
            return;
        }

        line.positionCount = agent.path.corners.Length;
        line.SetPositions(agent.path.corners);
    }
}
[Issue](https://youtu.be/jZG3RKcYHOs)
```

One thing I've noticed was that if I did not have a ridigbody on the enemies, it would fix the issue kind of... but I want those enemies to have that component.